# Symfony2 Doctrine ODM embeded class form validation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, odm

I have a Doctrine mongodb document that I have turned into a form. The document has two emebedOne documents, that are also in the form. The main document is being validated, but the embed docs are not. I am using custom asserts but I don't think that should matter.

Document

```
    class AccountRecord{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="BimcoreEmail")
     * @Assert\Email
     * @Assert\NotNull
     * @CustomAssert\BimcoreEmail
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * Access Admin
     * 
     * @MongoDB\Boolean
     */
    private $access_admin = 0;


    /** @MongoDB\EmbedOne(targetDocument="vidAccountSettings") */
    private $vid;
   }
```

embeded class the custom assert on this is never called.

```
/** @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument */
class vidAccountSettings {
    /**
     * Share section path
     *
     * 
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="Url")
     * @CustomAssert\Url
     */
    private $sharePath;
}
```

form

```
class AccountEditFormType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * Builds the embedded form representing the user.
     *
     * @param FormBuilder $builder
     * @param array       $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options){
        $builder
            ->add('prefix', 'hidden', array('required' => false))
            ->add('vid.access', 'checkbox', array('required' => false))
            ->add('vid.googleAnalytics', 'text', array('required' => false))
            ->add('vid.liveRail', 'text', array('required' => false))
            ->add('vid.sharePath', 'url', array('required' => false))
            ;
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'intention'  => 'editAccount',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'bimfs_account_creation';
    }



}
```

handler

```
class AccountEditFormHandler
{
    protected $request;
    protected $userManager;
    protected $form;

    public function __construct(Form $form, Request $request, BimcoreAccountManager $accountManager)
    {
        $this->form = $form;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->accountManager = $accountManager;
    }

    public function process($account)
    {
        // set the data in the form for the current account.
        $this->form->setData($account);

        if ('POST' === $this->request->getMethod()) {

            $this->form->bindRequest($this->request);
            if ($this->form->isValid()) {
                $this->onSuccess($account);
                return true;
            } else {
            }
        }

        return false;
    }


    protected function onSuccess(BimcoreAccountRecord $account)
    {
        // update the account data.
        $this->accountManager->updateAccount($account);
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Cory

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out, you need to set a assert valid statement into the record for the embeds you want to validate.

```
/** @MongoDB\EmbedOne(targetDocument="vidAccountSettings") 
    * @Assert\Valid
    */
    private $vid;
```